# Как хранить внешний объект? C++

Tags: c++

Нужно в классе хранить массив внешних объектов, так чтобы при изменении в классе-контейнере, объекты менялись не только локально. Без  stl. Вот, что у меня есть:

```
class AdultDepartment: virtual public Building{
protected:
    Patient *places;
    int *days;
    int count_places;
```

а вот метод добавления нового объекта:

```
void addPerson(Patient &p){
            addDays();
            Patient *temp;
            if(places != nullptr){
                temp = places;
                places = new Patient[count_places];
                for(int i = 0; i < count_places - 1; i++){
                    places[i] = temp[i];
                }
                delete []temp;
                places[count_places - 1] = p;
                cout << places[count_places - 1].getName() << endl;
            } else{
                places = new Patient[1];
                places[0] = p;
                cout << places[0].getName() << endl;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Откуда взялось странное требование «без STL»?

Comment: Наверное по аналогии с бустом ("придется тащить ВЕСЬ stl!!!")

Comment: Мне кажется, логичнее было бы хранить указатели на объекты - тогда не будет вопроса об "объекты менялись не только локально". Имеет смысл резервировать некоторый объем памяти для будущих объектов, т.е. хранить размер массива и его заполнение (кстати, вы `count_places` при добавлении не обновляете!), а при полном заполнении увеличивать его, скажем, в 2 раза - ну, по принципу работы вектора в STL.

Comment: @VladD обычно такие ограничения приходят из студенческих заданий, а в итоге всё сводится к созданию своего STL с блекджеком. В данном случае какого-нибудь vector<shared_ptr>.

Comment: @Harry в addDays() увеличиваю